# Clicked 'do not show again' on a prompt in PhpStorm, how to undo?

Tags: phpstorm

I had a notification in PhpStorm:

> Debug session was finished without being paused. It may be caused by
> path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote
> projects. To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration
> for 'example.com' server at PHP | Servers or enable Break
> at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
>
> Do not show again

I clicked 'Do not show again' by mistake, and I'd like to undo that - I would like to see this warning when it happens. How can I undo "do not show again" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug | Advanced settings | Notify if debug session was finished without being paused`.